# Favorite list iOS 6 position data

Tags: objective-c, ios6, favorites

I want to load my data from `sqlite database` and position it on the view (one photo and the description).

How can I put the data in position X and Y after load it from the database?

I did a image to explain it (I'm developing for `iphone 5`):
[image]

I think it maybe I can do it with `CGRect` but I don't know exactly how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to say that I used another better solution than that.

On the iOS 6 we have a new thing called: [CollectionViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewController_clas/Reference/Reference.html)

[image]

It's a really better solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure how to explain without giving a code as answer. but as a normal multidimension loop. Calculate the position and add the new image in the current subview (if able to do so).
The following not tested:

[EDIT: updated for correct indentation and syntax error]

```
   CGFloat IMAGE_WIDTH = 150;
   CGFloat IMAGE_HEIGHT = 150;
   CGFloat LABEL_PADDING = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < [TOTAL_ROWS]; i++) {
    // this is the initial frame for each row
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, i * IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
    for (int j = 0; j < [TOTAL_COLUMNS]; j++) {
        // but for column we need to more the x.position so its not stacking on itself
        newFrame = CGRectMake(IMAGE_WIDTH * j,
                              newFrame.origin.y,
                              IMAGE_WIDTH,
                              IMAGE_HEIGHT);

        UIImageView *newImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:newFrame];
        newImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
         // create a label at the bottom of the image
        UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(newFrame.origin.x,
                                                                      newFrame.origin.y +
                                                                      newFrame.size.height +
                                                                      LABEL_PADDING,
                                                                      newFrame.size.width,
                                                                      newFrame.size.height)];
        [newLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"description %d", j]];
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(newFrame));
        [self.view addSubview: newImageView];
        [self.view addSubview: newLabel];
    }
}
```

Comment: `CGRectMake` only accept floats, I'm missing something here, when I try implement your code it give me an error there, something about 'int' data on the 2nd for.

Comment: my bad Fabio, see updated answer now. CGRectMake need 4 parameter, miss another one CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)

Comment: Yes you are right, know I'm have only a doubt about the 2 last lines, can u explain it? I have an warning tell me that `addSubView` doesn't exist. Thank for your help

Comment: then probably you using UIViewController. to add subview use `[self.view addSubview: ..]`. subview means adding some element as a child to another parent element.

Comment: I have the code without errors but I can't get any result, only a blank page... I put some breakpoints and it runs all code, I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: where do u actually run the code? do u have the image? are u adding to the correct view? if u don't have the image consider setting `[newImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]` to simulate image. sorry. im not on my device with Xcode. will test it later.

Comment: Yes I have the image, I created a ViewController, I did a method with the code and called it on viewDidLoad. I'm adding it on the self.view. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've fix the example. i've put the wrong value in y position. please correct them. Figure out the correct position and track by `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(newFrame));`

Comment: I tried put i<1 and j<1, I see the image now, but I only can see the entire image if I put LABEL_PADDING=100 . I thinks it's now a size problem. You really helped.

Comment: alright. as long as u got how it works. you can figure out the rest. consider accepting this answer if it is the correct solution to help others. sorry couldnt test the code. try my best to read in the edit field alone.

Comment: I only changed the X value because the space between the images, and now it's perfect! Thank you!